# Bulk load causing schema drift in files (adf pipeline or mapping dataflows)

Tags: azure-data-factory

Bit of a challenge here

I have around 45,000 historic .parquet files
partitioned like this **yyyy,mm,dd** (2021/08/19) in the **dd** level I have 24 files (one for each hour)

The columns in each day file are pretty wide, anything up to 250 columns.  It has increased and decreased over time, hence there being schema drift when trying to load into SQL using mapping dataflows that made the file larger.

Around 200 of those columns I require and I know what they are. I even have them in a schema template.  The rest are legacy or unwanted

I'd like to retain the original files in blob as they are, but load files with those 200 columns per file into SQL.

What is the best way to achieve this?

1. How do I iterate over every file but only take the columns I need?
   I tried using a wildcard path

   '2021/**/*.parquet'

within mapping dataflows to pick up All files in blob so I don't have to iterate creating multiple clusters or a foreach

2. I'm not even sure how to handle this or whether it should be a copy activity or a mapping df
   both have their benefits but I think I can only use mapping df if I need to transform parts of these files in depth.
3. should I be combining the months or even years into a single file then trying to read from this files so I can exclude the additional from the columns I want to take into SQL server.

ideally this is a bulk load that need some refinement when it lands.

Thank in advance

Comment: I haven't done this before but I know that data copy requires a pretty strict match between source and target columns if you are using auto mapping. If your target table is missing a column in the source, it won't auto map and it will fail. You could try defining one dataset and manually map columns through but if the file doesn't match the dataset it might fail. So I don't think that's your solution.

Comment: What comes to mind is a once-off databricks job to go through all of the raw parquet files and rewrite them in a consistent format, as Spark is generally more flexible WRT metadata. I haven't used data flows enough to know whether it's useful in this case. dataflows just compile down to spark (databricks) code (which is in turn compiled down to java) anyway

Comment: Agreed with nick this is usually my approach to schema drift!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a data flow to the pipeline and use a Select transformation to choose the columns you wish to propagate. You can create pattern-based rules in the data flow Select transformation to choose the columns that you wish to pick from each file schema.

Comment: I got there in the end. I'm still working on a memory issue with loading to the sink by ideally this worked. 
For a faster way of doing the select you can edit the code (if you have a lot of columns) and add in the list you need to return

Comment: You can use pattern-based rules instead of naming each column 1x1

Comment: Thanks looking into it now. Do you have any tips on dynamic naming? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68894918/rename-blob-folders-with-copy-foreach-loops ?