# Rename Blob folders with Copy Foreach loops?

Tags: regex, azure-data-factory

I have a hierarchy of parquet files in my blob stored as

> yyyy/MM/dd/yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss_[source].parquet

The dd folders contain multiple files throughout a 24hr period at least one an hour.

examples across folders:

> 2018/04/01/2018_04_01_06_37_14_ABCXYZ01.Parquet

> 2019/10/03/2019_10_03_21_52_34_ABCXYZ01.parquet

> 2020/08/23/2020_08_23_03_00_13_ABCXYZ01.parquet

I would like the folder structure to look like this after the copy.

> Year=2019/Month=04/Day=01/2019_04_01_00_00_00_ABCXYZ01.Parquet

I'm probably going to need to copy all 8GB of these files and iterate through but the dynamic content code is what's throwing me off.

Any help on approach would be great. if I do not need to iterate can I use a copy activity and the copy behavior? [image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you need to dynamically generate your folder path in your sink dataset. Please check below implementation for better Idea.**

Step1: GetMetaData activity to get file names from source folder dynamically.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1mNG.gif)

Step2: ForEach activity to iterate each file and inside ForEach activity I am dynamically generating destination path format and storing it in to newPath variable.
expression used in Set variable:
[Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UAAD.png)
[ForEachSetVariable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7udAz.gif)

Step3: Inside ForEach Activity, Copy activity Sink dataset with dynamic parameters to take new Path.
[ForEachCopy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP6kB.gif)

Comment: Thank you, Sorry it took so long to test this. 
It works exactly as discribed

Comment: I think I have an issue though. The same file is being copied over and over but with a different file name @ShaikMaheer-MSFT

Comment: I think I found the error of my ways. I had a *.Parquet statement still in the source file name instead of the item().name.

Comment: I've created an additional variable CurrentPath. 
@{split(item().name,'_')[0]}/@{split(item().name,'_')[1]}/@{split(item().name,'_')[2]}/
So I can tell the source were to find the files as they are in a hierarchy and I want the wildcard to look through months rather that days /2021/**/*
concurrency set to 5 and ForeachLoop Batched at 20.  
I start to experience files from day 20210101 containing 20210102 files
Any ideas why?